# Steam will not install in 19.04

Tags: software-installation

I am trying to install Steam in 19.04 but getting errors.

```
sudo apt-get install steam
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package steam is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  steam-launcher

E: Package 'steam' has no installation candidate
```

Also tried

```
sudo apt-get install steam-launcher
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package steam-launcher is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'steam-launcher' has no installation candidate
```

and

```
sudo apt install steam-launcher
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package steam-launcher is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'steam-launcher' has no installation candidate
```

Comment: And have you enabled the partners repository?

Answer (score 2):

Download the .deb file from the official steam website.
( https://store.steampowered.com/about/ )

After you download it, right click -> properties -> permissions -> Allow executing file as program. You have to put tick there.

Close the properties, then double click the icon. It should open in the software center ready for install.